# What forces are involved to enable a rock to skip in water?

Tags: classical-mechanics, popular-science

Does the surface tension matter or is it something else that is providing the upward force? Can someone explain the phenomenon to me physically?

Comment: There are some references to "serious" analyses of the problem in this article: http://discovermagazine.com/2003/aug/featscienceof